# How to create such a mechanism?

Tags: rigging, bones, drivers, mathematics

I thought to do it sideways. Here you need to use drivers and math, I think. But where can I find similar examples in execution, tutorials with a solution to a similar problem? Or books, videos, articles on sections of mathematics that would help create such a mechanism.

Tell me the sources of information that would help create such a mechanism and in the future know where to get knowledge to resolve such issues. I will be grateful)

[image]

Comment: Hello, this site is preferably for focused questions. Here it is a bit hard to understand at which step of the problem you need help.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this effect by using a cast modifier and instancing. Create a plane and use edge loops and cut once down the middle and a few times on the side. Then delete everything besides the middle edges to create a single line of vertices. Then in the object properties for it, set instancing to vertices and add a cast modifier. Then create the rectangles or whatever else you want to be moving up and down. Then set the relations for its object properties to be the line of verts you previously made. This should instance the rectangle to all the verts on the line.

Now create an empty, and in the cast modifier settings you added to the line, set the object to be the empty. Make sure to clamp it to the Z axis as well in the modifier settings. Mess with the scale and radius settings until you get the effect you want.

[image]